# Injecting dynamic style tag is cached

Tags: javascript, css

I have two small questions regarding the following code:

```
export function loadCSS(path) {
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  const style = document.createElement('link');
  style.href = path;
  style.rel = 'stylesheet';
  head.appendChild(style);
}
```

1. Will the browser serve the file from cache?
2. Will this code block the rest of JS until the CSS file finished to load?

Comment: To avoid browser cache, you scan add an always changing parameter to the end of the url. If the path is changed, the file will be loaded again. Try something like `style.href = path + '?random=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);`. I think CSS will be loaded in a separate "thread" so JS execution will not blocked.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is if it will be cached as a regular tag?

Comment: Yes, if you don't change the url it will be cached, unless you explicitly set No-Cache headers in your html meta tags.

Comment: _“but my question is if it will be cached as a regular tag?”_ - wrong question; browsers cache _resources_, not “tags”. (This might seem nitpicking; but it is important for general understanding that you also get the terminology right.)

Answer (score 0):

1. The browser can serve it from cache, to be on the safe side, use cache busting, that means appending a random query to your path: (for server side control check cache-control (new) and expires (old) headers)

   `style.href = path + "?" + Math.random();`
2. If the href is defined on the link before appending, it will be render blocking. A better alternative is to add an invalid media attribute, append the link and then remove it to trigger download:

   `function generateLink(node){//node is some reference within head 
                       var link = document.createElement("link");
                       link.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
                       link.setAttribute("type","text/css");
                       link.setAttribute("media","invalid");
                       link.setAttribute("href",someHref);
                       ((node && node.parentNode) || (document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]))
                       .insertBefore(link,node || null);
                       setTimeout(function(){link.removeAttribute("media")},17);
                   };`